# R summary output not printing formula, but only its variable

Tags: r, output, formula, glm, summary

I my R code, I have the folllowing:

```
input.formula = 'some_valid_formula'

glm.model <- glm(inp.formula,data=data, family='quasipoisson')

summary <- capture.output(summary(glm.model)) 

print(summary)
```

The problem is that the summary prints:

> Call: [INFO] - model coefficients: glm(formula = input.formula, family =
>   \"quasipoisson\")
>   ...

Note that the formula is printed as the formula variable name and not the formula itself.  What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `summary(glm.model)` show you?  Obviously, if that also shows a similar summary, then your wrapping it in something else would likely not add any new information.

Comment: `summary.glm` shows the same output as `capture.output(summar(glm.model))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `do.call` to construct and execute the `glm` call. This will return the evaluated `glm` call with the formula displayed. For example:

```
data <- data.frame(group = gl(3,3), type = gl(3,1,9), counts = rpois(9, 2))
input.formula = "counts ~ group + type"
glm.model <- do.call("glm", list(input.formula, 'quasipoisson', data))
summary(glm.model)
```

Comment: Is there really no other way? That seems really painful.  The original problem also causes subsequent calls to anova to break since it can't fetch the formula.